# How can I publish my game (*.aab file) on google play?

Tags: unity, google-play, google-play-services, build-process

[image]

[image]

I select arm64 (64 bit) and x86 and amrv7 and select build app bundle in player setting so but when I want publish so I have an error like :

Error

This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 2. Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.

---

I tried following the steps listed in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55984197), but the problem remains.
PLease answer me, why no people answer in this web site?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. When I searched for the error message you listed, I found [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55974331). Does that Q&A address your problem?

Comment: Why no one answers me

Comment: Dear pikalek , I upload like https://stackoverflow.com/q/55974331  but Ihave This Error also , Why ???? I do ot kow , I test for 10 time and I have  it also

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean by "I have this error also." Are saying that you followed the solution in the link that I posted & you still have the same error?

Comment: PIkalek , yes Right ,I followed the solution in the link that YOU posted & Istill have the same error Google play can ot accept my games and I see:

enter image description here

enter image description here

I select arm64 (64 bit) and x86 and amrv7 and select build app bundle in player setting so but when I want publish so I have an error like :

Error

This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 2. Include 64-bit and...... (in above post)

Comment: Sorry to hear that didn't resolve the problem. I edited your question to include the extra information. Regarding the lack of answer: it's probably the case that nobody who's read this question has a solution.

Comment: PLease answer me, why no people answer in this web site?

Answer (score 2):

I received the exact same error yesterday when I tried to publish a new update of the app. Apparently Google has made some changes internally. I had done about 30 builds before for this particular app, so I couldn't fathom what the difference was.

What solved it for me was unchecking the `x86` checkbox in the project settings.

This allowed my build to pass. I did get a notification that my new build would be supported by less devices. I checked the difference and the difference was '2'. From 12657 to 12655 devices.

I am not a 100% sure what the exact reason is that the `x86` build is rejected, but what I read on other forums was that it had to do something with missing `x64` libraries in the `x86` build. (but feel free to correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: Immorality,Hello ,Thanks I will try for publish like you, but I have 2 questions  Dd you uncheck ARMV7 also or not (Only x86)? 2-Does arm64 support x86 device (=means 64 bit support 32 bit devices) Or not ?

Comment: I only unchecked x86. Armv7 and arm 64 were left checked. I don't know about arm64 support

Comment: Immorality ,very Thanks, ,I will test it , what is your minimum api in playersetting unity(api 16 or api 21)? because I  selected 16 api.

Comment: Minimum is set to 16 for me

Comment: I read minimum api for 64 bit is 21 in android official site so if you could publish with api 16 it is good

Comment: -Thanks ,it worked.  thanks  but in app purchasing  c# code do not work now, what is your in app purchase code  in unity? can you help me ,my games stopping for 4 months ...please help me for In app purchase code....

Comment: This is unrelated to in app purchasing. You probably have something else going sour.

Comment: ,yes I know , But when I update my game (not change coding) So do not run in app purchase ... this is my link for purchasing and errors  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614248/what-is-code-for-iapin-app-purchase-in-unity-2019-1-9      please help me