# Game not accepted in Google Play even though it's built in 64 bit (Unity)

Tags: unity, google-play

I tried building my game according to the google play rules, but I get the following error message:
"This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 1.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code that it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app."

According to the documentation (https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) for Unity I should get a working version when I do:

1. Set Scripting Backend to IL2CPP
2. Select the **Target Architecture > ARM64 checkbox
3. Build as normal

I've built the game both as APK and as AAB, but neither are accepted. I am using Unity 2018.3.14f1.

I have downloaded this NDK: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64.zip and put the content to: C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Android

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unchecked x86 from "Target architecture" and then make AAB for "ARM 64" and "ARM7" upload it to google play.

Some one on stack overflow answered it and he mentioned it due to x86 google play was not accepting the AAB. I am sorry i don't have link to that question.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: This worked indeed. The question you refer to was probably here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/174907/how-can-i-publish-my-game-aab-file-on-google-play?rq=1

Comment: Yep you are right that was the question i want to mention. I am glad it helped.

Comment: Note that the reason it was complaining is that you were providing a 32-bit version for x86 devices, but not a version for x86_64 devices.